# in slim, how to embed a style at the top of a script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I'd like to embed a style at the top of a script in a slim template. Something like this:

```
style
  .thumbnail_large {
    border: 1px solid red
  }
```

but this is not working. Any idea how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
css:
  .thumbnail_large {
    border: 1px solid red
  }
```

This is the Slim syntax for [embedded engines](https://rdoc.info/gems/slim/frames#embedded-engines-markdown).